# Which one is correct? When asked to comment / When he being asked to comment / When asking to comment / When he asked comment

Tags: passive-voice, ellipsis, to-infinitive, bare-infinitives

I'm doing my grammar homework, but it really kills me.

> ( ).He refused to given any explanation.
>
> A. When asked to comment on the quality of the goods.
>
> B. When he being asked to comment.
>
> C. When asking to comment on the quality of the goods.
>
> D. When he asked comment on the quality of the goods.

I think it may be A, how about you? Could the subject 'he' be omitted in sentence A?

And sentence B is a bit odd yet I don't understand totally how to use 'being', the others are more, but I am not very sure.

Comment: Does it actually say "He refused to **given** any explanation"?  Because that is wildly wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Well, logic suggests that, once someone asked him for a comment, he refused to answer, that's what the option A implies

The option C would mean that he asked for a comment himself and also refused to answer (was he speaking with himself? I doubt -- that doesn't make any sense)

Comment: So only A can express passive-voice and have no grammartical false, right?

Comment: @beau yeah that's right

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in saying that it is option A; however, it is important that you learn why you are not sure about your answer. It's because you don't know the particular structure used in A. Let's examin it:

*He refused to given any explanation when asked to comment on the quality of the goods.*

Something has been omitted in the above sentence. I'm putting the omitted part in parantheses below:

*He refused to given any explanation when (he was) asked to comment on the quality of the goods.*

If you still have a problem, let's reverse the order of the above sentence:

*When (he was) asked to comment on the quality of the goods, he refused to give any explanation.*

Hope that helped.